# Stylesheet primary={false} not working in react js

Tags: reactjs

[image: This is my folder structure]

```
This is my Stylesheet.js:


import React from 'react'
import "./mystyle.css "

function Stylesheet() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="primary">Dhoni</h1>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Stylesheet
```

---

```
This is my App.js:

import './App.css';
// import Myroutes from "./Myroutes.js";
import Stylesheet from './Stylesheet';


function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Stylesheet primary={false} />

    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is mystyle.css:

```
.primary {
  color: orange;
}

.font-xl {
  font-size: 52px;
}
```

I've not used Myroutes.js in this case. I'm not getting any errors in console or otherwise.

**Expected Output:**

No css should be applied to the text called "Dhoni". i.e a black text.

Comment: Your definition of `Stylesheet` does not accept any props like `function Stylesheet(props)`

Comment: You need to pass primary as a prop to your Stylesheet component and use it as a prop with the className.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works:

```
This is my Stylesheet.js:

import React from 'react'
import "./mystyle.css "

function Stylesheet({primary}) {
 return (
  <div>
   <h1 className={primary}>Dhoni</h1>

  </div>
)}

export default Stylesheet;



This is my App.js:

import './App.css';
// import Myroutes from "./Myroutes.js";
import Stylesheet from './Stylesheet';


function App() {
 return (
  <>
   <Stylesheet primary={false} />

  </>
)};

export default App;
```

Comment: it doesn't work. it's only coming black only now.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you really want to get `<h1 className={false}>`?